# PHP - Changing content dynamically

Tags: php, arrays, variables, dynamic, reload

Alright, so I have a PHP app that, in essence, fills up an array with references to elements in an XML file, does a shuffle() on the array to randomise it, then cycles through the array, displaying the data from the array (and ergo the XML file) on the screen.

My current code works fine - It fills the array, shuffles it, and displays the 0th index (which -is- random). My problem lies in the fact that **I want to be able to reload the content on the page dynamically, without losing the data in the arrays, but not link to a different page**. More specifically, I want to be able to cycle through the array on the click of a button (without totally reloading the page, losing the valuable data in the array).

I tried using some hidden form fields to load the values of the array into a temporary array, then feed them back in as the page reloads, but to no avail. I find a lot of bugs this way, and it's quite clearly a quick-n-dirty way of doing it.

Essentially, I want the code to do something like this:

```
$heaps_array = array(...); // Populated by, let's say 3 strings, for argument's sake
shuffle($heaps_array);
echo $heaps_array[0];
// User clicks the Next button...
// Get rid of the $heaps_array[0] from the page content, and...
echo $heaps_array[1];
// User clicks the Next button...
// Get rid of the $heaps_array[1] from the page content, and...
echo $heaps_array[2];
// User clicks the Next button...
...
```

Comment: Perhaps you're looking at AJAX then?

Comment: if you realod the page the data has to be stored: in a file, a db, session, cookie, parsed via post\e\get in hidden form. the best option depends on your situation

Comment: if the order is random then all you need to know is the last one(s) see by the user, picking a new random that excludes already seen, that should be a lot less data to move about.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a / is request based interpreter language so you need to run a script every time you need something from server. You can't have those arrays always in memory without using some storage engine (memcached, MySQL, you name it).

As others have said, you can send the array to the frontend and manipulate it in JavaScript. That way you won't load the server and have all data in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you send the array to the client side (the dirty way, not ajax) ?
Then display values with js.

i mean:

```
echo 'var array = new Array('.implode(',', $array).');';
```

Otherwise you will need more sofisticated method, the best is to build a mini webservice and get values through an AJAX query.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here, but you need to understand that PHP is a server side language that runs and finishes before the browser even sees the page content. To do dynamic content, thats where javascript and ajax come into play. I recommend a javascript framework such as jQuery that makes AJAX calls simple.

Some ways to do it:

1) Output the entire php array into a javascript variable on page. Do all of the array sorting using javascript. No AJAX.

2) Use php to sort the array, store it in a session variable. Use AJAX to request new data from the array in session memory, resort the array if necessary and return the value you need.

3) Use an AJAX call to request and return the entire sorted PHP array. Use javascript to do with it as you wish.

Depending on the size of the data you wish to return, you may want to minimise amount of data request through AJAX and the client side processing, and just use PHP to do all of the array stuff then return the exact values you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing PHP's session management out there since no one has.  http://php.net/session_start